# Change the max. #of simultaneous actors allowed inside python script

Tags: python, python-multithreading, ray

I have a remote class like (using `ray` API)

```
@ray.remote
class className
   ....
```

And I want to start 60 or more instances of this class and let them do some work simultaneously.

However, I can't start more than 50 instances of this class at the same time.

How can I change the max. number of threads allowed at any given time from inside of the python script?

Comment: Hey. Did you find a way to solve this? The answer below seems not solving it!

Comment: @Yahya unfortunately not. sorry.

Comment: Same is here. I am running it on Windows 10, if you're doing the same, then you need to know that this seems to be a bug on Windows OS in particular

Comment: @Our why can't you run more than 50 instances? How do you try to execute it and what's the error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use Custom Resources. I put a few links of interest below:

- [Specifying required resources](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/walkthrough.html#specifying-required-resources)
- [Resources with actors](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/actors.html#resources-with-actors)
- [Resources keyword argument in the API reference](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/package-ref.html?highlight=resources)

The idea is that you first provide a dictionary to the `resources` argument of `ray.init`. Each key of the dictionary corresponds to the name you give to a custom resource. The value associated with the key is the maximum resource number available for this specific resource; whichever value you put, you can think of it as representing 100%. It is usually helpful to put values that relate to the execution of specific tasks/actors. For example, in your case, you want to have 50 actors from the same class executing at the same time, so 50 makes the most sense.

```
ray.init(resources={'Custom': 50})
```

Now, `resources` is also an argument for `@ray.remote`. It similarly requires a dictionary, equivalent to the one provided to `ray.init`. So let's say you have your class definition:

```
@ray.remote
class MyClass(object):
    # Methods
```

You can limit the number of Actors concurrently executing for this class by providing a custom resource value which will compare to the one defined in `ray.init`. The value must be an integer, except if it is lower than one; dividing the value given in `@ray.remote` by the corresponding one in `ray.init` and multiplying by 100 gives you the percentage of this custom resource that each task/actor will require. In your case, you want to set a limit of 50 actors, and we set `Custom` to 50 in `ray.init`. Hence, if each Actor requires a value of `Custom` equals to 1, then only 50 Actors will be able to run at the same time.

```
@ray.remote(resources={'Custom': 1})
class MyClass(object):
    # Methods
```

No more than 50 actors of this class can now concurrently execute.

Comment: "No more than 50 actors of this class can now concurrently execute.": But I want exactly the opposite of this; being able to run more than 50 actors concurrently.

Comment: Oh, OK, well it seems I misunderstood your question then. Can you edit your question and better explain what you mean by "However, I can't start more than 50 instances of this class at the same time."? Thank you.

Comment: I'll try but in the mean time, this is the error what I am getting from your suggested solution: ...

Comment: "worker.py:1047 -- The actor or task with ID ffffffffffffffffef0a6c220100 is pending and cannot currently be scheduled. It requires {Custom: 60.000000}, {CPU: 1.000000} for execution and {Custom: 60.000000}, {CPU: 1.000000} for placement, but this node only has remaining {memory: 1.220703 GiB}, {CPU: 3.000000}, {object_store_memory: 0.390625 GiB}, {node:10.18.235.95: 1.000000}, {Custom: 40.000000}. In total there are 0 pending tasks and 1 pending actors on this node. This is likely due to all cluster resources being claimed by actors."

Comment: "To resolve the issue, consider creating fewer actors or increase the resources available to this Ray cluster. You can ignore this message if this Ray cluster is expected to auto-scale"

Comment: I am sorry, there was indeed a mistake in the values given to `Custom` in both `ray.init` and `@ray.remote`. It should run now. :)